# How can I insert html into navbar with registerHelper?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Here is my html:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    {{chooseScriptLevel
                            'Home'
                            'zhŭyè'
                            '主页'
                    }}
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Here is my helper:

```
     Template.registerHelper('chooseScriptLevel', function (english, pinyin, simplified) {
     var userSkillLevel = Meteor.user().profile.skillLevel
     switch (userSkillLevel) {
    case 0:
        return english
        break
    case 1:
        var ruby = '<ruby>' + simplified + '<rt>' + pinyin + '</rt></ruby>'
        return ruby
        break
    case 3:
        return simplified
        break
    default:
        english
}
})
```

My navbar is showing: `<ruby>主页<rt>zhŭyè</rt></ruby>`. Literally showing the html tags to the user.

How can I get it to show the user this:

zhŭyè
 主页

If I do it manually, like this, , it works:

   `<li><a href="/" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <ruby>主页<rt>zhŭyè</rt></ruby>
          </a></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use triple braces around your helper - this is necessary if the helper returns html:

```
{{{chooseScriptLevel 'Home' 'zhŭyè' '主页' }}}
```